# How to compound Jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am not really sure how to word this question (that's probably why I haven't found an answer yet).  I want to compound the effects of a Jquery animation. Specifically I am looking to create a custom scroll so that when an arrow is clicked, the `<div>` moves up slightly.

I thought I would use the `animate` function with relative units, but when I try to repeat the animation, it does not work.  Here is the basic code:

JavaScript:

```
$(".arrow-down").click(function(){$('#t1').animate({marginTop: '-=50px'});});
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "text">
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    <div id = "t1">
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: __PLEASE__ please please please do not implement a custom scroll. They are the absolute __worst user experience__. You might as well make people print out your page on paper to read it.

Comment: @Mathletics Ok, but then how do you fix the scroll bar from slicking out past the div and giving the website an overall cheap look?  I am an amateur and would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: What is the problem? Here's a demo which seems fine: https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/gafp91gb/

Comment: By "slicking out" do you mean the overscroll on OSX? Or do you mean having visible scrollbars at all? I promise you, a janky custom scroll looks much "cheaper" than browser default scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the desired effect or do you want it to move back up upon pressing the arrow twice?

```js
$(".arrow-down").click(function() {
  $('#t1').animate({
    marginTop: '+=50px'
  });
});

$(".arrow-up").click(function() {
  $('#t1').animate({
    marginTop: '-=50px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <button type="button" class="arrow-down">\/</button>
  <button type="button" class="arrow-up">/\</button>
  <div id="t1">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is the desired effect.  Thank you for your answer.  Your example actually helped me find the answer.  When the div moves up it overlaps the  arrow, not allowing the arrow to be clicked again.

Comment: Sorry, the fix that I implemented was to position it with a higher z-index then the scrolling div in order to allow the button to be pressed again when the div scrolls up